# Detect when control key was already pressed outside the application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I have following scenario:

[image]

In this when i drag and drop any folder on grid then it opens one window having import option and if i press control key when i comes on application while drag-drop then it surpasses that window and directly imports file.

Up to this point i have coded the functionality.

But i wanted to add one condition in it where in if control key is pressed outside the application (while dragging and dropping), then it should also surpass that wimport window.

For that i tried but it neither detects the keydown event nor satisfies `if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl))` condition if control key is pressed outside the application while dragging and dropping the folder.

I have kept condition as follows:

```
if (!bFound)
{
    if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl))
    {
        return;
    }
    // bool isImportEnabled = true;
    string caption = checkDropContent(files);//, out isImportEnabled);
    WindowImport win = new WindowImport(dbc, this, caption);//, isImportEnabled); //Opens Import XAML Window
    win.paths = files.ToList<string>();
    win.ShowDialog();
}
```

kept debugger, but does not work.

Comment: check this http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/detecting-ctrl-key-while-using-drag-drop-help-14313922.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a global keyboard hook, there's a [good article about it on the codeproject site](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C).